# Android Chromecast application crashes when using Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, chromecast

When I export a Signed Application Package for a Chromecast application with Eclipse by using Proguard it crashes when I execute it on target devices.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
```

to Proguard configuration file `proguard-project.txt`!